# Cannot Visualize Image Embeddings on TensorBoard

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I wanted to visualize the fashion_mnist dataset on TensorBoard but I'm getting the following error
[Image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC6TO.png).

The final aim is to get a visualization like below:
[GIF in official mnist repo](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist/raw/master/doc/img/embedding.gif)

I followed everything according to this tutorial -> https://towardsdatascience.com/taking-the-tensorboard-embedding-projector-to-the-next-level-bde53deb6bb7.

My full code is given below

```
%load_ext tensorboard
import csv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import mnist_reader

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("resnet_50.h5")

embeddings = tf.keras.models.Model( 
    inputs=model.inputs, 
    outputs=model.layers[-1].output 
)

# Load Data
# Change Data folder respectively
data_folder = "./data"
train_images, train_labels = mnist_reader.load_mnist(data_folder, "train")
test_images, test_labels = mnist_reader.load_mnist(data_folder, "t10k")
train_images = train_images.reshape(-1, 28,28)
test_images = test_images.reshape(-1, 28,28)
test_images = np.stack((test_images,)*3, axis=-1)

images_pil = []
images_embeddings = []
labels = []

for img, label in zip(test_images[:100], test_images[:100]):
    img_pil = Image.fromarray(img).resize((28,28))
    img_embedding = embeddings(tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0))
    images_embeddings.append(img_embedding)
    images_pil.append(img_pil)
    labels.append(label)


with open(f'logs/embeddings/feature_vecs.tsv', 'w') as fw:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter='\t')
    csv_writer.writerows(images_embeddings)


one_square_size = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(len(images_embeddings))))
master_width = 100 * one_square_size
master_height = 100 * one_square_size
spriteimage = Image.new(
    mode='RGBA',
    size=(master_width, master_height),
    color=(0,0,0,0) # fully transparent
)
for count, image in enumerate(images_pil):
    div, mod = divmod(count, one_square_size)
    h_loc = 100 * div
    w_loc = 100 * mod
    spriteimage.paste(image, (w_loc, h_loc))
spriteimage.convert('RGB').save(f'logs/embeddings/sprite.jpg', transparency=0)



with open(f'logs/embeddings/metadata.tsv', 'w') as file: 
    for label in labels:
        file.write(f'{label}\n')


%tensorboard --logdir logs  --host localhost
```